# Testing KnockoutJS applications with JestJS

Tags: knockout.js, jestjs

I am currently using Jasmine to test my Knockout application along with requirejs. Is it possible to test the same application with JestJS? I am intending to run test in parallel.

Thanks,
Ankit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jest doesn't support requirejs (AMD modules) out of the box so you would have to transpile your AMD modules to CommonJS with a [scriptPreprocessor](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#scriptpreprocessor-string).

Additionally if you're using more advanced requirejs features such as plugins / custom resolve rules then you might run into further issues.

Comment: what if my modules to be tested use RequireJS? Can I import the same requireJS dependencies in Jest test file using import?

Comment: @AnkitTanna As I say Jest doesn't support AMD modules so you'd need some way to allow AMD to interoperate with commonJS or ES modules such as a transpilation step -- I've been unable to find an AMD -> CommonJS babel transformation however, they all seem to go from CommonJS -> AMD. It might be worth trying to write your own, perhaps using https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins//transform-es2015-modules-commonjs as a guide.

Comment: Thank you @riscarrott. I am planning to cast my AMD module to CommonJS and then test the code. I am not sure if this should be practiced but it saves time in test suit which is all what matters. http://skookum.com/blog/converting-a-project-from-amd-to-cjs-with-recast